# Refresh Access Database with latest data C#

Tags: c#, oledb

Im currently extracting data from an external Access Database file. This file is updated on a regular basis, say 2 - 3 minutes. So i have a timer in my application that checks for new rows at a specified interval. Although I am not getting the new rows immediately.

I am creating a new connection at each interval but still not getting the latest rows. Do i need to refresh? Add something to my connection string ? Kindly help, thanks.

My connection string

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\ZKTeco\ZKAccess3.5\Access.mdb"
```

Comment: Do not change connection string. Its the same. What you use to present data from database? DataGridView?

Comment: I'm posting directly to my application database. MSSQLSERVER